# URL no netbeans não funciona

Tags: php, apache, netbeans

Estou tentando executar um projeto no php no netbeans e ele executa a seguinte url:

```
http://localhost/portfolio/index.php
```

Só que meu projeto não abre. Ele só abre na seguinte url:

```
http://localhost:8080/portfolio/index.php
```

Como faço para abrir ele na url correta toda vez que eu clicar em F6?

Comment: Você está utilizando qual servidor? Apache?

Comment: isso mesmo, estou usando o apache

Comment: Tem outra aplicação rodando na porta 80? Caso não altere nas configurações do seu Apache para não escutar na porta 8080 e sim na 80, assim quando você acessar da primeira maneira que mencionou na sua pergunta irá funcionar, se lembre de reiniciar o serviço.

Comment: Tem outro jeito, você alterando nas configuraçoes do netbeans, dessa forma, ele vai abrir na porta 8080 sme precisa ficar alterando manualmente. Vou postar como.

Comment: Olha, acho que tem sim. Eu no caso tava usando o instalador do mysql e só depois disso que não consigo mais acessar a url normal. Esse instalador fez com que tudo funcionasse perfeitamente no visual studio. Porém precisarei mexer com o netbeans também, será que é uma configuração que preciso fazer no netbeans ou no próprio apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode setar a porta `8080` diretamente no seu projeto do netbeans, desta forma, ele vai abrir a url corretamente, sem que você precise alterar o `httpd` do apache:

1. Clique com o botão direito do mouse sobre seu projeto netbeans, e
   selecione **Propriedades**;
2. Na janela que abrir, no menu lateral a esquerda, selecione
   **Executar Configuração**;
3. Na parte direita da janela, altere a url do campo **URL do Projeto** de `http://localhost/portfolio/` para `http://localhost:8080/portfolio/`, assim sempre vai abrir na porta correta toda vez que você executar o projeto.

Comment: Resposta clara e objetiva.

Answer (score 3):

Vá no seu projeto click com o botão direito, vá em propriedades e depois em executar configuração. É só alterar URL do projeto.